# ¿Cómo puedo insertar imágenes en mysql y mostrarlas en PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, html5, wamp

quiero guardar imágenes en base de datos subiendolas desde un formulario para luego mostrarlas en una página. El problema es que solo se guarda el tipo de archivo.
Este es el formulario

```
<div class="imagenes">
    <form action="almacenar.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="imagen">Imagen:</label>
        <input type="file" name="imagen" id="imagen">
        <input type="submit" name="subir" value="Subir Imagen">
       </form>

    </div>

Este es el código para almacenar
include('conexion.php');

//Verificar si el tipo de archivo es un tipo de imagen permitido y que el tamaño no exceda 16mb
$permitidos = array("image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png");
$limite_kb = 16384;

if (in_array($_FILES['imagen']['type'], $permitidos) && $_FILES['imagen']['size']<=$limite_kb * 1024){
    //Archivo Temporal
    $imagen_temporal = $_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'];
    //Tipo De Archivo
    $tipo = $_FILES['imagen']['type'];
    //Leemos el contenido del archivo temporal binario
    $fp = fopen($imagen_temporal, 'r+b');
    $data = fread($fp, filesize($imagen_temporal));
    fclose($fp);
    //Escapamos los caracteres para que se puedan almacenar en la DB
    $data = mysqli_real_escape_string($data);
    //Realizamos la consulta
    $resultado = "INSERT INTO imagenes (imagen, tipo) VALUES ('$data', '$tipo')";
    mysqli_query($conexion, $resultado);
    if ($resultado){
        echo "El archivo ha sido copiado exitosamente";
    }else{
        echo "Error al copiar el archivo";
    }}
    else{
        echo "Formato de archivo no permitido o excede el tamaño limite de $limite_kb kbytes";
    }
```

Los errores
[image: al momento de subir la imagen]
[image: lo que se muestra en la db]

Comment: No es recomendable guardar directamente una imagen en una db. Lo más optimo es guardarlas en un direcctorio y guardar el path a la imagen en un campo de la db.

Answer (score 1):

No te esta guardando lo que aparece en $data, te diría que ni bien llega el código a esa parte, hagas esto a ver te te trae:

```
$data = fread($fp, filesize($imagen_temporal));
var_dump($data);
exit;
```

O sea, antes de guardar `$data`, revisemos QUE HAY en `$data`.

Lo que te aparezca ahí, es lo que estas tratando de guardar en tu tabla, y quizás excede el tamaño del campo de la tabla (depende como lo tengas configurado en `mysql`).

Tema aparte, en realidad lo ideal seria algo diferente, es decir, no guardar *binariamente* la imagen en la tabla de `mysql`, sino subir la imagen a una carpeta y en la tabla de `mysql` solo guardar su nombre y su carpeta. (a menos que por algo especial desees hacerlo en forma binaria), pero el 99% de los sitios web lo hacen acumulando las fotos en una carpeta y luego solo consultando el nombre en la base de datos.

Aquí te dejo un tutorial de como se hace:

[Link a tutorial upload imagenes](http://blog.unijimpe.net/seguridad-en-upload-de-archivos/)

Comment: gracias amigo funciono, te agradezco

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="save.php" method="POST"  enctype='multipart/form-data' name="formblog">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="colFormLabelLg" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-lg">Titulo Del Articulo</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="titulo del articulo" name="title" value="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="colFormLabel" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-lg">Autor</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Autor" name="autor"value="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="colFormLabelLg" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-lg">Imagen</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="img">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="colFormLabelLg" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-lg">Articulo</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
    <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="txtArticle" placeholder="Introduzca su texto Aquí..." name="articulo"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
    <input class='btn btn-outline-primary' name='btnGuardar' type='submit' value="Publicar Articulo">
</form>
```

Ahora el php

```
<?php 
    include ("../conexion/conexion.php");
    include ("sesion.php");
    $titulo = $_POST['title'];
    $autor = $_POST['autor'];
    $archivo = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];
    $imagen = "../img/".$_FILES['img']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($archivo,$imagen);
    $articulo = $_POST['articulo'];

    if (empty($titulo) || empty($autor)  || empty($imagen) || empty ($articulo)) {
        $_SESSION['message'] = 'Llena Todos los Campos por favor o selecciona una imagen valida!';
        $_SESSION['message_typed'] = 'danger';
        header("Location:blog.php");
    } else {
        $query = "INSERT INTO articulo (fecha,titulo_articulo,autor_articulo,imagen,contenido) 
                VALUES(NOW(), '$titulo', '$autor', '$imagen', '$articulo')";
            $result = mysqli_query($conexion,$query);
            if (!$result) {
                die ("Error al Insertar");
            }
            $_SESSION['message'] = 'Articulo Guardado Satisfactoriamente';
            $_SESSION['message_typed'] = 'success';
            header("Location:blog.php");
    }
 ?>
```

Como ves guardo la url de la imagen, es cuestion de traerla y ya asi:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM articulo ORDER BY fecha DESC";
      $rsul = $conexion->query($sql);
      while($row = $rsul->fetch_assoc()){
        ?>
        <br><br>
        <h1><?php echo $row['titulo_articulo']?></h1>
        <p><?php echo $row['fecha']?></p>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4"><!-- colocar url de la pagina cuando se suba al dominio https://agrocontable -->
          <img class="img-fluid" whidth="289.98" height="130.19" src="<?php echo "http://localhost/dev".$row['imagen']?>">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <p><?php echo $row['contenido']?></p>
            <i><strong><?php echo $row['autor_articulo']?></strong></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <?php
      }
        ?>
```